# Love2D: Calling two files

Tags: love2d

Okay so i have two files one named Player.lua and one named Main.lua

Main:

```
function love.load()
end

function love.update()
end

function love.draw()
end
```

Player:

```
function player.load()
end

function player.update()
end

function player.draw()
    love.graphics.setColor(255, 0, 0)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill", 50, 50, 50, 50)
end
```

Output is just a black screen!

Comment: Hello, Ras. M, and welcome to Game Development! Maybe you can improve your question by expanding the description of your work, and better addressing your issues, so that we can better understand and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main.lua` file is automatically executed from the Löve application and  the overriden functions `love.load`, `love.update` and `love.draw` get called.

This means that if in your main.lua file you've included the love.load function, at the start of the game that function is called; then, if there's a love.update function, it gets called too, then the love.draw if it's present, and then back to update, draw, update, and so on.

So the player.lua file will never gets executed, unless you tell the program to execute it from main.lua.

main.lua

```
function love.load()
    require "player.lua"
    player.load()
end

function love.update()
    player.update()
end

function love.draw()
    player.draw()
end
```

This is how it should look like.